# Vuetify VMenu with nested dropdown issue slot activator

Tags: vue.js, menu, vuetify.js, dropdown

I am trying to create a custom VMenu with nested dropdowns that can be either hovered to expand the nested dropdowns or clicked to choose a dropdown itself as the value.

Here is my current code so far:

The v-menu definition:

```
<v-menu offset-y :close-on-content-click="false" open-on-hover>
                        <template v-slot:activator="{ on : menuHeader, attrs }">
                            <v-btn
                            text                 
                            v-bind="attrs"
                            v-on="menuHeader"
                            
                            >
                            {{menuItem.title}}
                            <v-icon
                                dark                              
                                center
                            >
                                    mdi-chevron-down
                                </v-icon>
                            </v-btn>
                        </template>
                        
                        <nodes-list                             
                            :nodes="menu.filter(p => p.id === menuItem.id || p.parent_id !== null)" 
                            :parent_ids="parentIds(menuItem)">
                        </nodes-list>
                    </v-menu>
```

The nodes-list component:

```
<v-list>
        <template v-for='node in myNodes'>
            <v-list-group v-if='nodes && nodes.filter(p=>p.parent_id == node.id).length > 0' :key="node.title">
                <template v-slot:activator>
                    <v-list-item @click="listener">
                        <v-list-item-title>{{node.title}}</v-list-item-title>
                    </v-list-item>
                </template>
                
                <node-list class='py-0 pl-3' :nodes='nodes' :parent_ids="parentIds(node)"/>
            </v-list-group>
            <v-list-item class='py-0 pl-8' @click="listener" v-else :key="node.title">
                <v-list-item-title>{{node.title}}</v-list-item-title>
            </v-list-item>
        </template>
    </v-list>
```

The problem is that I need to click the nested dropdown to expand further the nodes-list, the activator is triggered by the click how can I trigger it on mouse hover?

Maybe some insight on how I can trigger the activator would help, let me know if you need more detailed code!